# django display in html

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-template-filters

I have two classes in my models:

```
class FicheFormation(models.Model):
    intitule=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    duree=models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    objective=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    niveau=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    prix=models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    comptecf=models.ForeignKey('CompteRF',related_name='fichecompte',null=False)
    unite= models.ManyToManyField('UniteFormation', related_name='unitefiche')
```

and

```
class UniteFormation(models.Model):
    nomUe=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    acronyme=models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    commentaire=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
```

and I want to display the list of formations of a comptecf,

so i write in my view this method:

```
def getFormation(request):
 #   user = request.user
 #   if user and user.is_active:
 #   u=user.username
    c=CompteRF.objects.all().filter(username='Me')
    queryset=FicheFormation.objects.all().filter(comptecf=c)
    return render_to_response('formation.html', {'formations':queryset},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and in my formations.html:

```
% for car in formations %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ car.intitule}}</td>
                <td>{{ car.objective }}</td>
                <td>{{ car.unite }}</td>
            </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

update:

```
{% for car in formations %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ car.intitule}}</td>
                <td>{{ car.objective }}</td>
        % for car in formations %}
                <td>{{ car.unite.nomUe }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
            </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

it works for =car.intitule and car.objective but for car.unite it displays None, I haven't understand why because normaly it displays unite 'Sarra', in the console I need to do : c=unite.all() and then c[0].nomUe and it works and affich 'Sara' but in my view or html when i try to iterate on car.unite I have en error message !

Comment: What error message? How are you iterating on `car.unite`?

Comment: I did :  % for car in formations %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ car.intitule}}</td>
                <td>{{ car.objective }}</td>
  % for car in formations %}
                <td>{{ car.unite.nomUe }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
            </tr>
{% endfor %}

Comment: Please put that as an update to the question, with proper formatting. You seem to be iterating over `formations` twice, rather than over `unite`.

Comment: Well `unite` is a many to many relationship, so which of the (possible) many is it supposed to show?

Comment: it's supposed to show many UniteFormation

Answer (score 1):

To loop through the related `unite` objects, you need to loop through `car.unite.all()`. In the template, you drop the parentheses, so you do something like:

```
<td>{% for unite in car.unite.all %}{{ unite.nomUe }}{% endfor %}</td>
```